# magento add BCC to form submit button

Tags: magento-1.9

I use custom form for FAQ and I would like when customer submists form, it would also generate mail and send it to certain email address.

```
<button class="button" title="Send" type="submit" >
<span><span><?php echo Mage::Helper('faq')->__('Send')?></span></span>
</button>
```

Same way you can use `->addBcc('em@ail.com')`?

This is complete submit.phtml code:

```
    <div class="mc_submit_question">
<h4 class="title"><?php echo Mage::Helper('faq')->__('Add more Questions please') ?>:</h4>

<?php 
    $faqs = array();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('faq/faq')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->addEnableFilter('1');
?>

    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('faq/submit/save')?>" name="myForm"  method="post" onsubmit="return(validate());">
        <div class="mc_faq_field">
            <?php echo Mage::Helper('faq')->__('Select a Subject')?>:<p>
            <select name = "category">
                <option ><?php echo Mage::Helper('faq')->__('---Select Subject---')?></option>
        <?php 
                foreach ($collection as $faq)
                {
                    echo '<option>';
                    echo $faq->getFaqname();
                    echo '</option>';
                }
        ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="mc_faq_field">
            <?php echo Mage::Helper('faq')->__('Question')?>:<p>
            <textarea name = "question" rows="8" cols="100"></textarea>
        </div>

        <!-- insert code here -->
        <?php
            $_product_submit_question = "";
            $_product_submit_question = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qpro');
            if($_product_submit_question != ""){
        ?>
        <div class="mc_faq_code_mail">
            <?php echo Mage::Helper('faq')->__('Your Email:')?><p>
            <input type="text" name ="customer_email" value=""></input>
        </div>

        <div class="mc_faq_code">
            <!-- <h4><?php //echo Mage::Helper('faq')->__('Product:')?></h4> -->
            <input type="hidden" name ="product_id" value="<?php echo $_product_submit_question; ?>"></input>
        </div>

        <div class="mc_faq_code">
            <input type="hidden" name ="is_customer" value="1"></input>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <!-- end insert code here -->      

        <div class="mc_faq_code">
            <?php
                $im = imagecreate(60, 20);
                $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 0 , 0, 0); 
                $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
                $random=rand(1000,9999);
                imagestring($im, 10, 10, 2, $random , $textcolor);
                $filenametemp="media".DS."gif".time().".gif";
                ImageGIF($im, $filenametemp); 
                $ImageData = file_get_contents($filenametemp); 
                $ImageDataEnc = base64_encode($ImageData); 
                unlink($filenametemp);      
            ?>
            <?php echo Mage::Helper('faq')->__('Security Code')?>:<p>
            <input type="text" maxlength="4" name ="code"></input>

            <img alt="<?php echo $random ?>" src="data:image/gif;base64,<?php echo $ImageDataEnc?>"">
            <input type="hidden" name="codetest" id="codemd5" value="<?php echo $random?>"/>

        </div>

        <div class="box_bt">
            <button class="button" title="Pošlji" type="submit" >
                <span><span><?php echo Mage::Helper('faq')->__('Send')?></span></span>
            </button>
            <button class="button" title="Povrni" type="reset">
                <span><span><?php echo Mage::Helper('faq')->__('Reset')?></span></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Form validation code will come here.
function validateEmail()
{
   var emailID = document.myForm.customer_email.value;
   atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
   dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
   if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) 
   {
       document.myForm.customer_email.focus() ;
       return false;
   }
   return( true );
}

function validate()
{
   if( document.myForm.category.value == "---Select Subject---" )
   {
     alert( "Prosimo, če vnesete kategorijo." );
     return false;
   }

   if( document.myForm.question.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Prosimo, če vnesete vaše vprašanje." );
     document.myForm.question.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   if( document.myForm.customer_email.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Prosimo, če vnesete e-mail naslov." );
     document.myForm.customer_email.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   else {
        var emailID = document.myForm.customer_email.value;
        atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
        dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) 
        {
            alert( "Prosimo, če vnesete veljaven e-mail naslov." );
            document.myForm.customer_email.focus() ;
            return false;
        }

   }

   if( document.myForm.code.value == "" )
   {
        alert( "Prosimo, če prepišete varnostno kodo." );
        document.myForm.code.focus() ;
        return false;
   }

   return( true );
}
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `->addBcc()` function needs to be called on an object with a class of either `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template`, `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info` or `Zend_Mail`.

Have a look how this is used in the core, for example in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php`:

```
public function send()
{
    /** @var $emailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
    $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
    // Send all emails from corresponding list
    while (!empty($this->_emailInfos)) {
        $emailInfo = array_pop($this->_emailInfos);
        // Handle "Bcc" recipients of the current email
        $emailTemplate->addBcc($emailInfo->getBccEmails());
        // Set required design parameters and delegate email sending to Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
        $emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $this->getStoreId()))
            ->setQueue($this->getQueue())
            ->sendTransactional(
                $this->getTemplateId(),
                $this->getSender(),
                $emailInfo->getToEmails(),
                $emailInfo->getToNames(),
                $this->getTemplateParams(),
                $this->getStoreId()
        );
    }
    return $this;
}
```

As I've seen in your code above you're calling a `saveAction` from your modules' controller. So you can implement it there (for example) and not in your `.phtml` file.